# needed Clarification in using AWS ses email services

Tags: email, amazon-web-services

I am planning to integration aws ses in my web application .
I have few questions

1. Do I need to verify all from (source email ids) each time I call AWS SES APLI ??
   Because I need to send using different email ids each time. (if yes can some one quickly tell me how in java )
2. As each mail host has out bound email limit ,does it applies in AWS SES mail as well??
   Because If I user @gmail.com I have limit to some values (per day) .How amazon handles this?
   will it check the limit break or should develop logic to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

You can verify a single email address or an entire domain.

If you want to verify an entire domain, you just need to set a few DNS records, see [Verifying Domains in Amazon SES](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/verify-domains.html) for more details.

SES has quota limits, these limist are dinamyc, if you need to change them manually follow  [Increasing Your Amazon SES Sending Limits](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/increase-sending-limits.html)